# In C++, finding repeated peak values in array and calculating pulse

Tags: c++, arrays, mbed

First of all I apologise in advance, I'm very new to programming and any help at all is greatly appreciated. I am using mbed to program a microcontroller:
my goal is to check an array for peak values:

```
void peakvals(int array[],const int count);{     //count = size array = 10, meant to find peak vals in array
    int peakcount=0;                             //meant to record the number of peak vals occurring
    for (int i=0;i<peakcount;i++){                
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++){                   
        if ( array[i]==array[j] ){  
            peakcount=1;                         
            peakcount++;                         
        
        }
    }
```

My overall goal is that I would like to then take this code and output an estimate for pulse rate first waiting for a couple seconds to accumulate values and give an accurate reading, then update every 1 second.
I hope my question is clear enough and thank you for your time

Comment: The syntax of is not good (ie: the code doesnt compile). Here my suggestion. Check each elements of the array starting from position 1, up-to last -1, and check if neighbor (previous, next) position are lower than current. If yes, increment the number of pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggest in the comments, a simple function could looks like this:

```
int count_peaks(const int array[], const int arrsize)
{     
    int peakcount=0;                            

    // NOTE: C++ index start at 0, so (arrsize-1) is the last element you can access in the array.
    for (int i= 1; i < arrsize - 2; ++i)
    {    
        // Temporary variables are just to clarify the code, you can do it one-liner below instead.
        const int previous  = array[i-1];
        const int current   = array[i];
        const int next      = array[i+1];
        
        // if( array[i] > array[i-1] && array[i] > array[i+1])
        if( current > previous && current > next)
            peakcount++;
    }
    return peakcount;
}
```

Where you look previous and next elements of the array.